# Thomson TG858V8 looses connections with Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230

Tags: router

I recently purchased a Alienware M14x R2 with a Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 card. Using this new laptop I have experienced some weird problems with my router (Thomson TG858V8).

Here is a brief description:

1) If I connect the Alienware before any other device to the network, then when I try to connect a device it can't. For example, I turn on the laptop then I turn on the Xbox 360 and the Xbox 360 can't get a connection. It solves until I reset the router, then everything works ok, if I connect the Xbox 360 then the laptop everything works fine.

2) This thing only has happened me once and do not know if it is related but I turned off my router then the laptop instantly got a BSOD.

3) If I connect another laptop to the network and the alienware is sleeping, then when I wakeup the alienware it can not get a connection.

Any ideas on what may be happening?

Comment: What was the error on the BSOD? Hard to tell if it is related if we don't know the error message. Anything in the event logs for that incident as well, or really anything that stands out in general related to networking? Do you have another router that you can try?

Comment: Most likely you have some devices using DHCP and some with static IPs and the static IPs are inside the router's DHCP block. If you're going to configure some devices with static IP addresses, they should have IP addresses that are inside the router's LAN subnet but outside its DHCP range.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz all my devices have DHCP.

Comment: @MaQleod https://dl.dropbox.com/u/597069/report.html is the 28/10/2012 07:49:07 p.m. thought it appears that all my BSOD are network related...

Comment: If you're up to it, you'll want to have a look at those minidumps to see what actually failed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263 - Otherwise I'd suggest updating drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the Thomson TG858v8's firmware to v8.2.7.8 will fix the problem. See link below

http://community.plus.net/library/hardware/fixing-wireless-compatibility-problems-with-the-thomson-585v8/

Firmware can be found here: http://download.modem-help.co.uk/mfcs-A/Alcatel/Modems/TG585/v8/Firmware/r8-2-7/Generic/

Comment: Can you add more information to this answer. If the link ever changes your answer will become useless.